# How to make the top menu fill the width on a restored window?

Tags: discussion, bug, design

If you open Stack Overflow in Chrome, restore do window for the horizontal scrollbar to show up, an see the top menu, you will see some space on the right:

[image]

Actually, if you check with the inspector, not even the body is filling the width.

Is there a way to make the menu fit and fill that empty space?

Obs. the code we can see with Chrome's inspector. I did try, but I don't know how to say "fit the window+scroll width". Also, I couldn't reproduce this "error" with a simple jsfiddle. It will work there inside the div.

Google's search results page top bar is another example.

[image]

For Google's page it works if you remove the `width:100%` from `div#viewport`, but while it fixes for small window, it will break the layout for a bigger window. So a media query would be the only answer, maybe?

Comment: Good question! I never noticed that

Comment: This should either be on Meta, or it should include the code in the question - otherwise when this is fixed it will be useless to future users of the site.

Comment: I don't get this bug in my Chrome on Mac. This is probably a Windows thing.

Comment: @Jeff the code can be seen on Chrome's inspector. I couldn't reproduce it in a small example. I used stackoverflow as example, but there's a lot of websites with this issue. Google's search results page top bar is another example.

Comment: Yup, I get that but my point was that it won't be able to be inspected once someone at SE fixes their code 6 months from now

Comment: @Jeff I think it need to be running on a full window page to happen. So it can't be reproduced in a snippet. But it's a common design "problem" that happens in lot's of websites. I updated the question with one more example.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
body {
    font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    color: #242729;
    background: #FFF;
    min-width: 1075px;  <----This is the issue
}
```

to

```
body {
    font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    color: #242729;
    background: #FFF;
    min-width: 1090px;
}
```

### Alternatively

Change all `1060px` in `all.css` to `1045px`

Comment: It works, but isn't there a not hard coded way? I would like to say "fill the window+scroll width"

Comment: it is filling the window! i don't understand what you mean?

Comment: I think It's not the best design to use fixed sizes like this. There should be some way to say, in css, "fill all" (independent of exactly how many pixels is "all").

Comment: i am not using fixed sizes its already in `all.css` there is a property `padding:15px` in footer and content DIVs of the website. which is causing the trouble because `1060px + 15px + 15px = 1090px` but in reality stackoverflow's developers have used `1060px + 15px = 1075px`

Comment: Got it... right, it's a solution. Now I would start another question about 'why fix 1060px?', maybe there's a more flexible way (like w3schools website). Anyway, thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that:

For Google's page to works, you would remove the `width:100%` from `div#viewport`; but while it fixes for small window, it will break the layout for a bigger window. So a media query would be the only answer I see here.

For stackoverflow, you would just make the body `position: absolute`; again, for the small window only, so a media query would be the answer.

That said, if we talk now about design, not css programming, some websites will show the mobile version if the screen is too small. I think that's the best approach.